# selenium pass parameter to @Test from pageObjects Common function

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, parameter-passing

I'm in the process of developing an automation framework using Selenium Webdriver.

For every test case, I have many items to verify (eg. is user Login to the web application, is Gender checkbox exists on the page)

Then it will using Excel `WriteResultUtility` to write result in Excel based on predefined column name.

I have 20 test case, and I don't want to code it in each test case every time. (minimize the code for easy to maintain in future)

// Selenium Main Test Script

```
public class MyTestCase_01 extends SuiteBase{
Read_XLS FilePath = null;
Read_XLS FilePath_TestResult = null; //Location to store Output File
String TestCaseName = null; 
static int DataSet=-1;
public WebDriver driver;            

@BeforeTest
public void checkCaseToRun() throws IOException{        

    FilePath_TestResult = MyTestCase_0001_TestResult; //Each test case will have own Output file
    TestCaseName = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); 
}

@Test(dataProvider="MyTestCase_0001Data")
public void MyTestCase_0001Test(String ColTestCaseName, String ColUsername, String ColPassword) throws Exception{

    DataSet++;

    // add arguments to match  check_isUserLoggedIn(Read_XLS, String, String, int, String)
    Login_Page.toCheck_isUserLogin(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName);  
    Register_Page.toCheck_isGenderChkbxExists(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName);
```

// pageObjects Login_Page.java (I want to use this as common function)(but I have problem on the `FilePath_TestResult`, `TestCaseName` variables as it is different value for each test case)

```
public class Login_Page extends BaseClass{

    private static WebElement element = null;
    public static Read_XLS FilePath_TestResult = null;
    public static String TestCaseName = null;   
    static boolean Testfail = false;
    static int DataSet = -1;

    public Login_Page(WebDriver driver){
            super(driver);
    }
    public static WebElement toCheck_isUserLogin(Read_XLS xls, String sheetName, String ColName, int rowNum, String Result) throws Exception{
        try{
            Boolean isUserLogin = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isUserLogin"))).size()!= 0;               
            if (isUserLogin == true){
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_IS_USER_LOGIN, 
                        DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);
                Testfail = false;                   
            }else{
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_IS_USER_LOGIN, 
                        DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_FAIL);
                Testfail = true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
        return element;
    }
    public static WebElement toCheck_isGenderChkbxExists(Read_XLS xls, String sheetName, String ColName, int rowNum, String Result) throws Exception{
        try{
            Boolean isGenderChkbxExists = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isGenderChkbxExists"))).size()!= 0;
            if (isGenderChkbxExists == true){
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS,
                    DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);
                    Testfail = false; 
            }else{
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS,
                    DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_FAIL);
                Testfail=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
        return element;
    }
```

//SuiteUtility.java

```
public static boolean WriteResultUtility(Read_XLS xls, String sheetName, String ColName, int rowNum, String Result){            
    return xls.writeResult(sheetName, ColName, rowNum, Result);         
}
```

//SuiteBase.java (Initialize test data file)

```
public class SuiteBase {    

public static Read_XLS MyTestCase_01_TestResult = null;
public static Read_XLS MyTestCase_02_TestResult = null;
public static Read_XLS MyTestCase_03_TestResult = null;
public static WebDriver driver = null;


//Initialize Test Data file.
public void init() throws IOException{

    // Test Result location
    MyTestCase_01_TestResult = new Read_XLS(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\TestOutput\\MyTestCase_01.xls");
    MyTestCase_02_TestResult = new Read_XLS(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\TestOutput\\MyTestCase_02.xls");
    MyTestCase_03_TestResult = new Read_XLS(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\TestOutput\\MyTestCase_03.xls");
```

My goal are make it as common function so it can be reusable and minimize the code.

However, the FilePath_TestResult (refer to SuiteBase.java) is different variable for each test case.

(I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility`)
Am I do the correct way for declare `public static Read_XLS FilePath_TestResult = null;` part?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u pass the arguments to below methods

```
Login_Page.toCheck_isUserLogin(String...args);   
Register_Page.toCheck_isGenderChkbxExists(String...args);
```

and control the parameters which you want to test?
I will also suggest you to look at @AfterMethod where you can write the result of the previous test to the column which you want.
Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Hi @Mrunal Gosar, pls see my response below for `@AfterMethod`

Comment: Your first solution is failing because you are calling both the methods in one @Test only, you will need to make seperate tests if you want to report status seperate for both the methods. In your second solution colName is the value where you would want to log the status of that test. and in 5th argument is the result or status of the test. you need to make the signature as toCheck_isUserLogin(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName)

Comment: Hi @Mrunal Gosar, I have try with `toCheck_isUserLogin(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName)` but I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility`. Is it possible the way I do static reference is not correct? pls advice, thanks.

Comment: You need to run your code in debug mode and identify which parameter is null. I believe you know how to run your code in debug mode in eclipse/

Comment: Hi @Mrunal Gosar, both parameter is `null `

Comment: So now you know why you are getting null pointer exception. You can now either initialize them with proper values or see if they can be removed.

Comment: Hi @Mrunal Gosar, I solved my problem now after your suggestion, appreciate your help, have a good day.